# Default selected value in mvc5 dropdown

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a linq query that is binded to a @Html.dropdownfor. If I assign a value to the user's account and leave the page. When I go back to the page, It's default value or preselected value is "Choose a schedule" even when I have a value assigned to it from before. I need it to preselect to the value already stored in the database. It was preselecting correctly with this

```
 ScheduleBuilderList = _context.ScheduleBuilder.ToList()
```

until I binded LINQ query.
How can I get the database value to the be default value selected in dropdown without messing up the LINQ?

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ApplicationUser.ScheduleSum, new SelectList(Model.ScheduleBuilderList, "ScheduleSummary", "ScheduleSummary"), "Choose a schedule", new {@class = "form-control", id="dropdown"})
```

LINQ

```
ScheduleBuilderList = _context.ScheduleBuilder.Where(s => s.IsScheduleAssigned == false).ToList()
```

[image]

[image]

Full Actionresult code with recommended change below

```
 public ActionResult  EmployeeDetails(string id, ScheduleBuilder scheduleBuilder, ApplicationUser applicationUser)
{
    var user = _context.Users.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);

    if (user == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    var viewModel = new TierViewModel()
    {
        ApplicationUser = user,
        TierLevel = _context.Tier.ToList(),
        ScheduleBuilderList = _context.ScheduleBuilder
            .Where(s => s.IsScheduleAssigned == false)
            .Select(item => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = item.ScheduleSummary,
                Value = item.ScheduleSummary,
                Selected = item.ScheduleSummary == user.ScheduleSum
            })

    };

    var user1 = _context.Users.ToList();

    var schedule1 = _context.ScheduleBuilder.ToList();

    return View("EmployeeDetails", viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Your new linq query is filtering the value stored in database. You might want  .Where(s => s.IsScheduleAssigned == false || s == currStoredSchedule). This is just pseudo code because we don't know how your ScheduleBuilderList look like..

Comment: Setting the `Selected` value of `SelectListItem` is ignored when you bind to a model property using `DropDownListFor()`. Delete the `Selected = item.ScheduleSummary == user.ScheduleSum` line - its pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var ScheduleBuilderList = _context.ScheduleBuilder
                                  .Where(s => s.IsScheduleAssigned == false)
                                  .Select(item => new SelectListItem
                                  {
                                      Text = item.ScheduleSummary,
                                      Value = item.ScheduleSummary,
                                      Selected = item.ScheduleSummary == "usersvalue"
                                  });
```

Where the literal "usersvalue" should be replaced the value of `ApplicationUser.ScheduleSum` for which you are interested in. Then you should change a bit also your View, like below:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ApplicationUser.ScheduleSum, 
                      Model.ScheduleBuilderList, 
                      "Choose a schedule", 
                      new {@class = "form-control", id="dropdown"})
```

and your Model should replace the type of `ScheduleBuilderList` with the following type:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem>
```

Comment: I don't think I can declare ScheduleBuilderList because it's in viewmodel. For clarification I posted the full ActionResult method above with a screenshot of your suggested code. ScheduleBuilderList in my viewModel is listed like     public IEnumerable<ScheduleBuilder> ScheduleBuilderList { get; set; } to grab dropdown items.

Comment: @user6680 Great ! You should change this `IEnumerable<ScheduleBuilder> ScheduleBuilderList { get; set; }` to this `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ScheduleBuilderList { get; set; } ` inside your ViewModel definition.

Comment: @user6680 You have missed also one closing curly brace after the `Selected = s.ScheduleSummary == user.ScheduleSum`. You should add there this `}`

Comment: I fixed that part thanks, but I'm still getting errors. I updated the code and screenshots above. I'm guessing the second screenshot error is because of the first screenshot error. "Property ScheduleBuilderList is never used" is what I'm getting with this in viewmodel IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ScheduleBuilderList { get; set; }

Comment: @user6680 My bad...Sorry.It's a bit difficult writing code out of a code editor :( Silly error...instead of `s` you should use the `item`, since this is the name of the captured variable.

Comment: Thanks that removed the s=> issue, but ScheduleBuilderList still gets "'ViewModel.ScheduleBuilderList' is inaccessible due to its protection level" Code updated above with item See first screenshot for reference to error I'm referring to

Comment: @user6680 I supposed that this property should be `public`. So I didn't mention it. You should  mark this property as public, `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ScheduleBuilderList { get; set; }`. Not doing so, gets the default access modifier, which for a class field is private and for this reason you can't access it.

Comment: Oh my mistake. I left out the public keyword. The code runs without errors now, but when I go to the EmployeeDetails view, it still says "Choose a Schedule". user.ScheduleSum is the the stored value in the database that Selected in the LINQ is assigned to so I don't understand why it won't prepopulate in dropdown. Also I added                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("OUTPUT: " + user.ScheduleSum);
 to confirm the value outputs to console, which it does.

Comment: Does the value of  `user.ScheduleSum` for the user you tested it is an option in the drop down but it is not the selected one, when the page is loaded? One last thing that I could thing it would be to change the `==`, `item.ScheduleSummary == user.ScheduleSum`  to this  `string.Equals(item.ScheduleSummary,user.ScheduleSum, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` but honestly I can't get why the equals it wouldn't work in your case (provided that the latter it will work)

Comment: I just realized why it isn't working. The boolean where if it's set to False doesn't show schedules set to True that are already assigned. The schedule is already assigned so of course it isn't going to be listed. I changed the value to False with the schedule still assigned to test it and the schedule prepopulates like it's supposed to. So you were awesome. Thank you. I rewrote the LINQ as  .Where(s => s.IsScheduleAssigned == false || s.IsScheduleAssigned == true && s.ScheduleSummary == user.ScheduleSum) to fix this. Thanks for all your help

Comment: @user6680 Great ! You are welcome. I am glad tha I helped.